# How to bind an object to a ComboBox, but update a different object when it changes?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, combobox

I have a `Zone` object that contains

```
public int Block {get;set;}
```

I also have a configuration object which contains minimum and maximum `Block` values, which are 0 and 2 respectively.

I need to display a ComboBox with the range of valid values, but I need to have the selected value bound to `Block`.

What's the best way for me to do this?

I've been trying the following:

```
var blocks = new Dictionary<string, int>();
for (int i = _currentZone.Constraints.Block.Min; i <= _currentZone.Constraints.Block.Max; i++)
{
    blocks.Add("Block " + i, i);
}

var blocksCombo = new ComboBoxControl(blocks, GetCurrentBlockValue());
```

with ComboBoxControl defined as

```
public ComboBoxControl(Dictionary<string, int> comboItems, int? selectedValue)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    cboItems.ItemsSource = comboItems;
    cboItems.SelectedValue = selectedValue;
}
```

and the XAML defined as

```
<Grid>

    <ComboBox x:Name="cboItems" 
              SelectionChanged="combo_SelectionChanged" 
              Height="25" 
              SelectedValuePath="Value">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Key}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>

</Grid>
```

When the `combo_SelectionChanged` event is triggered I manually update the `Block` value, which isn't ideal.

What I'd like is to be able to set the combo box with the items in the dictionary, but when I change the selected item the value is bound to a different object - the `Block`. Is this possible?

If so, how can I implement this? If not, is there a better way for me to go about this than what I'm currently doing?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's as simple as changing you xaml to have...

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cboItems" 
          SelectionChanged="combo_SelectionChanged" 
          Height="25" 
          SelectedValuePath="Value"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Block}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Key}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Assuming the data context is setup correctly, you probably need to set the datacontext of the combobox to your Zone object at some point, maybe pass it along with the constructor...

```
var blocksCombo = new ComboBoxControl(blocks, GetCurrentBlockValue(), this);

public ComboBoxControl(Dictionary<string, int> comboItems, int? selectedValue, Zone zone)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    cboItems.ItemsSource = comboItems;
    cboItems.SelectedValue = selectedValue;
    cboItems.DataContext = zone;
}
```

edit:

Also I think Henk is right, you might want to change the dictionary to instead be a ObservableCollection of Block.  (actually just realized block is just an int, this will probably work as a dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood everything right. You have the combobox and want to bind to one specific zone?

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ValidValuesList}" ItemStringFormat="Block {0}" SelectedItem="{Binding MyZone.Block}"/>
```

This binds to

```
public List<int> ValidValuesList
{
    get { return new List<int> { 0, 1, 2 }; }
}
```

and to

```
public Zone MyZone { get; set; }
```

in your usercontrols DataContext.